# Accessing the owner object in mongoid association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

ActiveRecord has such [feature](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Accessing+the+owner+object)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :birthday_events, ->(user) { where starts_on: user.birthday}, class_name: 'Event'
end
```

But when I try to use it in mongoid association I get error:
"no implicit conversion of Proc into Hash"

So is there any alternative of this feature in mongoid?